# SQL Server how to show time of load with bcp?

Tags: sql-server, xml, import, bcp

I used the `bcp` utility to load a file into a table.

Now I want to know load time.

`bcp` shows the time of clock.

Time of clock and time of load are the same thing?

Comment: Is *Time of load* in your context the **point in time** where you start the upload, or is the *duration*?

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare 

    @Start DateTime, @End DateTime

Set @Start = GetDate()

bcp logic
Set @End = GetDate()

    Select DateDiff(minutes, @Start, @End) = LdTime
```